# Copy text from inside a <object>

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application. In some views I have an `<object>` element which loads an HTML from other site (they are some reports created with Pentaho). Those HTML are tables in HTML with some rows and style, and the user wants to be able to highlight the text of one row, copy and paste into other place. If I go to the URL loaded in the `<object>` I see the same table and I'm allowed to copy & paste.

My problem is that if I try to highlight some text loaded inside that `<object>`, it's impossible. The cursor changes to the one which appears when you are selecting text, but the text is not highlighted and copy does not work (nothing selected...).

Is there any way to allow copy & paste of text inside an HTML loaded in an `<object>`?

My `<object>` is like this:

```
<object id="pentahoServer" type="text/html" data="{{reportUrl}}" width="100%" height="{{reportHeight}}px"> </object>
```

Comment: All else being equal, nothing stops you from copying text from a frame. Most likely, the report page is explicitly preventing it.

Comment: Nop,  it isn't preventing it. As I said, if I go to that report directly, I can copy & paste without any problem.